# Unable to find expo project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm Unable to execute the expo start command.

$ expo start

[09:43:39] Starting project at C:\Users\Subrata\Desktop\example-app

[09:43:40] Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?

Comment: Hello! Try running `yarn` or `npm install` on the terminal at root of the project to install the dependencies. After install all dependencies you can run `expo start`.

Answer (score 0):

either you havent installed dependencies yet, which you can do by running `npm install`, or you might be outside the project folder, in which case just run `cd projectName`